# Error when remove a view from superview

Tags: ios, subview, addsubview

I'm new on iOS development and i got a trouble want to ask you.

My purpose is show a view (not full screen) upon base view and still see a parent on the back outside the subview. 
So i added a subview (subclass of UIViewController) upon current viewController, then i do to open the subview:

```
AViewController *a = [[AViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubView:a.view];
[a release];
```

Here it works and show this subview as i expected. On this subview, i have close button to close this subview and do like this on subview:

```
- (IBAction)BackTouchUp:(id)sender 
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

When i click to close button, i got an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS. When i remove [a release] command on the parent, it works, but there is a memory leak.

Can you please explain for me the cause of this error and how to resolve this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `AViewController` object (AViewController *a) in interface and in the implementation, initialize the value like below:

```
a = [[AViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubView:a.view];
```

and whenever you want to remove simply put `[a removeFromSuperview]` and in dealloc

```
[a release];
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. As you said, a is instance variable of parent, isn't it? But [a removeFromSuperview] is in the child view's code, how can i access to a variable of parent?

Comment: via delegate method, Create custom delegate or Post Notification for the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the a view tag no

```
[a.view setTag:3];
uiView *f=[self.view viewWithTag:3];
[f removeFromSuperview];
```

i think this will solve your problem

Comment: I guess it was called in AViewController